# ViewController pushed after long delay when pushed inside a closure

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, closures

In the landing page, i have used a closure to receive the api response from a helper class. Once i receive the response am navigating to another page. The control executes the pushViewController line but it takes a long time to navigate. Is it because of the closure? how can i fix it?

```
class LandingView: UIViewController
{    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    getStaticCountryAndStateList()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Navigation
func getStaticCountryAndStateList()
{
    WebAPIHelper.getMethod(methodName: "/Common/GetStaticCountryAndStateList", success: {(response)->Void in

let signInObj = SignIn(nibName: (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? "SignIn" : "SignIn_iPhone"), bundle: nil)
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signInObj, animated: true)
            }


    }, Failure: {
        (error)->Void in
        print("Error \(error)")
    })
}
}
```

Comment: The response from your API probably is taking too long... That's why the viewcontroller is pusher after a long delay.

Answer (score 1):

```
To push view controller fast in closure, you must access main queue. 
Below is code for accessing main queue in swift.

func getStaticCountryAndStateList()
{
    WebAPIHelper.getMethod(methodName: "/Common/GetStaticCountryAndStateList", success: {(response)->Void in

DispatchQueue.main.async {

 let signInObj = Payer(nibName: (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? "Payer" : "Payer_iPhone"), bundle: nil)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(signInObj, animated: true)
}

    }, Failure: {
        (error)->Void in
        print("Error \(error)")
    })
}
}
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async { } works well in simulator but it doesn't make any difference in the real device i.e iPad or iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Always perform in main thread for UI related stuff.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //update UI
 });
```

**Swift 3**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // update ui
    }
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async { } works well in simulator but it doesn't make any difference in the real device i.e iPad or iPhone.

Comment: @Mano, what do u mean here **but it doesn't make any difference in the real device**

Answer (score 0):

Push the view on the main thread not on the same thread as your web request.

Comment: Can u pl provide me a code sample for what you mean